# Let $y$ be a solution $y'=e^{-y^2}-1$ on $[0,1]$ which satisfies.....

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the problem which I am unable to solve:

> Let $y$ be a solution $y'=e^{-y^2}-1$ on $[0,1]$ which satisfies $y(0)=0.$ Then which of the following options is correct?
>   1.$\quad y(x)>0$ for $x>0$
>   2.$\quad y(x)<0$ for $x>0$
>   3.$\quad y$ changes sign in $[0,1]$
>   4.$\quad y \equiv 0$ for $x>0.$

$y'=e^{-y^2}-1$ gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-y^2}-1 \implies \int\frac{dy}{e^{-y^2}-1}=x +C, C$ being a constant of integration. Now I am stuck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the sign of $y'$ ?

Comment: y identically zero is a solution and the right hand side is Lipschitz

Comment: @girianshiido  sign of $y'(<0)$  is negative for $x \in [0,1].$ So,Is option 2 is the correct choice?

Comment: If any of those is correct, it's the fourth.  The function $e^{-y^2} -1$ is globally Lipschitz since $e^{-y^2}$ has a globally bounded derivative.  Therefore by Picard-Lindeloff, we have local uniqueness of solutions.  $y \equiv 0$ is a solution to the ODE, so there is a neighborhood of zero on which any solution is zero.  I don't see how to formally write up the iteration to show that $y$ has to be zero on the entire interval, but it should be true though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y\equiv 0$ is a solution that does not satisfy any of the first three options, then the last option is correct. As Chris Janigian points out in the comments above, [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard-Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) tells us that any solution to this ODE must be identically zero in some neighborhood of the origin. Optimization of that interval should lead to the desired result.